# How to dynamically update the style of the highlighted item in ui-select

Tags: angularjs, ui-select2, ui-select

I trying to update the style of the highlighted item and didn't find a way to do it.

I'm using [ui-select](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select) with multi-select and no jQuery.
any help will be appreciated.

idan.

Comment: Check this http://plnkr.co/edit/j2YdK96MXqW4qzjMZwmo?p=preview ..I have changed as yellow color for highlighting text..is this you want?

Comment: Sorry @Asik, but the yellow color that you used is set statically and not dynamically...
meaning that i get the required color to use from the server only after the page is loaded already.

Comment: Check this demo http://plnkr.co/edit/j2YdK96MXqW4qzjMZwmo?p=preview .. you can create the css dynamically from controller and you can set the color from controller itself. is this you expected? Shall I add this as a answer?

Comment: Hi @Asik,
I don't see any changes in the plnkr, it's the same as the previous one.
How does one create a css dynamically from a controller ?